# pandas read_sas "ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index"

Tags: pandas, sas, valueerror

I need some help... I got some troubles reading my sas table in python using the pandas function read_sas. I got the following error:

```
"ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index".
```

Here is the code I run:

```
import pandas as pd

data=pd.read_sas("my_table.sas7bdat")
data.head()
```

My sas table is pretty big with 505 columns and 100 000 rows.

Thanks all for your help.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe try reading the file in increments? (Set chunksize and iterator variables. ) See more on https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sas.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it does not fix the problem. I found a solution which is to convert my table to csv and use pd.read_csv to read it.

Comment: Make sure that the dataset does not have numeric variables defined with a length of less than 8 bytes.  Current release of read_sas does not handle those properly.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with few sas files. I solved it in 2 ways:
1. encoding

```
df=pd.read_csv('foo.sas7bdat.csv', encoding='iso-8859-1')
```

2. With sas7bdat library installed in Anaconda with:

```
conda install -c prometeia/label/pytho sas7bdat
```

In python file:

```
from sas7bdat import SAS7BDAT
f=SAS7BDAT('foo.sas7bdat').to_data_frame()
```

Comment: Thanks. I might suggest splitting these off into two answers. The `encoding` approach failed for me, but `sas7bdat` worked.

Answer (score 0):

A solution I found is to export my sas table as a csv file with the code down below:

```
proc export data=my_table
   outfile='c:\myfiles\my_table.csv'
   dbms=csv
   replace;
run;
```

After that, I use pandas function read_csv to read the csv file  I have just created:

```
import pandas as pd

data=pd.read_csv("my_table.csv")

data.head()
```

Hope this might help.

Comment: Did you also manage to find a solution if you don't have the option to export to csv in SAS ?

Comment: I only tried to export in csv format sorry... Maybe you can try to export your SAS table in txt format  and read it with pandas.read_table()